# How to copy app ( installed from software center) and send to another ubuntu computer

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and my friend also has Ubuntu 12.04, he does not have internet so I want to send my apps to his computer (apps that I have downloaded from software center). So how can I send apps downloaded from software center to his Ubuntu computer.

Comment: Dude i really didnt understand the steps given in that page , explain please.

Comment: Those instructions are pretty clear, what didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

First, I suggest you check about installed packages list about your and your friend's 12.04 by using a command like:

```
dpkg -l
```

Second, if all the same, at your 12.04, clean your apt cache by using a command like:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Third, type this command:

```
sudo apt-get install <some pkg you want to install>
```

Fourth, copy and install `.deb` files from your `/var/cache/apt/archives` to your friend's 12.04.

- I think you know how to install *.deb package files and there may be some ways better than I answered.

Comment: Note that it's highly likely that the OP would miss a dependency and mess up with the friend's computer.It would be better if he first check which packages he needs to copy.